# is it possible in a table 2 column have data different table and one column have fetch another table ->use angular js and mysql

Tags: mysqli, angularjs-directive

Is it possible in a table 2 column fetch data different table and one column have fetch another table ?
use  angular js and mysql and how we use ng-repeat here?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make two requests. Once both requests have been resolved, do some logic to put the data into one array (ctrl.data). Now you can just ng-repeat over $ctrl.data.

```
let promiseOne = Service.getData1();
let promiseTwo = Service.getData2();

$q.all([promiseOne,promiseTwo]).then((res){
   ctrl.data = doSomethingWithResponses(res[0] & res[1]);
})
```